# django-tastypie user resource always null

Tags: django, api, django-models, tastypie

I can't figure out why my UserResource is always displaying null for every object even though verified_by_id is correctly in the database for Observation model.

Relevant code:

### Model

```
class Observation(ProjModel):
    verified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'observation'
```

### Resources

```
class ObservationResource(ProjResource):
    verified_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Observation.objects.all()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        resource_name = 'observation'

class UserResource(ProjResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        resource_name = 'user'
```

### JSON

```
"objects": [{"verified_by": null}]
```

Comment: Have you added "UserResource" to your URL structure?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Please post it as an answer so I can accept that.

Comment: :-) don't worry, I spent a "little while" the other night on exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for saving me "some time" :=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that all referenced `Resources` are in your URL structure in order for them to appear.